# How to forward email to a group from a single email address?

Tags: email, bulk-email, email-address

My wife has a DotNetNuke website for her non-profit, and a that site has a "Contact Us" page. The "Contact Us" module only allows for the entry of a single email address as the recipient of the contact email.

She would like to setup something like a "help@mynonprofit.org" type of email address, and then have any emails sent to that address automatically forwarded to a list/group of people in the organization, so that any one of those people can respond.

My first thought was to setup something like a Yahoo Groups type of thing, but this organization deals with medical/patient issues and she is concerned about HIPAA and privacy issues caused by using a public group like that.

It is possible that I could try and re-code the module for DNN, but that's a lot of work.

Is there a technology or service to handle this type of thing?

Thanks - Todd

Comment: Check your mail server control panel/feature list -- it may support Mail Groups/Mail Lists. If it does -- create one and assign the members -- it will do exactly as you have described.

Comment: Agreed. Mail forwarding seems like the easiest way to do this. No coding required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most control panels have an option to set up mail forwarding to lists. Check there first, or if in doubt, contact your web host.